# Compilation Error in Construction of Binary Search tree

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I am building a binary search tree. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct tree_node
{
    int val;
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
};
void insert(struct tree_node **, int);
int main(void)
{
    struct tree_node *tree;

    tree = NULL;
    insert(&tree, 10);
    insert(&tree, 20);
    insert(&tree, 5);
    insert(&tree, 7);

    return 0;   
}

void insert(struct tree_node **tree1, int value)
{
    struct tree_node *temp, *start, *tem;
    tem = NULL;
    temp = (struct tree_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node) );
    start = *tree1;

    temp->val = value;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;

    if(*tree1 == NULL)
        *tree1 = temp;
    else
    {
        while(*tree1 != NULL )
        {
            if(value <= (*tree1)->val)
            {
                *tem = *tree1;
                *tree1 = (*tree1)->left;
            }
            else
            {
                tem = *tree1;
                *tree1 = (*tree1)->right;   
            }

        }
        if((tem->left) ==  *tree1)
            tem->left = temp;
        else
            tem->right = temp;
    }
    *tree1 = start;
}
```

I am getting a compilation error:

```
prog.c:44:5: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘struct tree_node *’ and ‘struct tree_node **’)
```

Why?

Comment: You should `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc()`, instead of `#include`ing `<stdio.h>` twice, by the way. While we're on the subject, you should write `temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));`

Answer (score 2):

Inside `if(value <= (*tree1)->val)`,

```
*tem = *tree1;
```

should be:

```
tem = *tree1;
```

You have the correct version in the `else` branch.

Comment: Hey, How can I print the root value. I am doing 
             printf("%d", tree->val ); in main() but getting RUN TIME ERROR.

Comment: @Naman - that is correct.  temp->value will print with that statement.

Comment: @Yu Hao - I posted mine, your's was already up.  Confirmation is always a good thing :)

Comment: @ryyker I am writing it in main. Sorry it was tree->val. Why RUN TIME ERROR.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how can I debug the program using debugger

Comment: Actually I think this is not a correct code. every insert in main is going in ``if block'' of insertion();

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
void insert(struct tree_node **tree1, int value)
```

`tree` is a pointer to pointer, and
and `tem` is a pointer
so statement:

```
*tem = *tree1;
```

should be:

```
tem = *tree1;
```